# Running composer network install in Hyperledger throws out an error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy BNA to Fabric but getting this error

```
$ composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a ~/Downloads/comment-network.bna 
✖ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
Command failed
```

Already got `docker` running.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
4a1452a6773a        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0      "peer node start"        14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
59221c711615        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.1.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
eec390a547e5        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-0.4.6   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
c7d462facea6        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0   "orderer"                14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
```

I installed Fabric using step 4 of this [guide](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools) then ran

```
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

prior to deploying BNA.

*EDIT:*

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.02.0-ce, build fc4de44

$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.13.2 (17C88)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.3.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: COMPUTER NAME
      User Name: USERNAME
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      System Integrity Protection: Enabled
      Time since boot: 13 days 18:28
```

Comment: can you confirm your docker version and OS version please, thanks.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony just updated the post. Anyways, if it matters, I am also using `docker-machine` to run Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded that my issue was because of me using `docker-machine` to run Docker instead of running Docker via daemon.

I solved it by adding the ports used to `VirtualBox`.